# Comparing two fields in a record in Strongloop

Tags: strongloop

I'm needing to create a filter that looks up all records that were sent in late. Is there any way to build a request that compares two fields in the record?

I tried something like this, but it will only say "not a date" and I'm not sure how to make it compare to another date field. Does this option exist? If not, what's the best way to do this?

```
{"where":{"sent_in":{"gt":"should_be_in_by"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* compare date fields with the gt operator. The operand must be a Date object. (That's how it is in my working code)
Can you try with something like this and see whether it helps? I am assuming that should_be_in_by is a ISO Format Date string.

```
{"where":{"sent_in":{"gt": new Date("should_be_in_by")}}}
```

Comment: This seems to be about comparing a field to a fixed date? I need to compare to a different field in the same record.

Comment: Ah! I didn't get it the first time. I don't think it's possible to compare 2 fields of the same record in a filter. Loopback documentation explicitly states this: {where: {property: {op: value}}}
Where:

property is the name of a property (field) in the model being queried.
*value is a literal value*.